# Python Django copying base-site template from source code to be able to change site name which is Django adminstration

Tags: python

Im making a Python application on Django,I created a website and opened the server to be able to see it on the browser , the site name is by default Django adminsration, i want to change it but i can't , I'm using this resource

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial02/

It showed me how to do that  , but i still can't change the site name, what i understood is that i need to copy the base-site html file from the source code to the place where i need to put my templates.

so i have to write the path of the folder where i need to put my templates in settings.py (templates dirs)

I think i don't know how to write the path in the settings.py (templates dirs).where should i put my templates new folder ,what about the slashes, shall i leave them as they are ?

G:\Semester 6\SE\code 1\mysite

mysite is my project folder 
it contains two other folders and the manage.py 
shall i create my templates folder here ?? and copy this path "G:\Semester 6\SE\code 1\mysite" and paste it in templates dirs settings.py??

and what to be do after that ?

then shoukd i copy that path insettings.py(tempaltes dirs) ??

another thing :
this resourse asks me not to forget to tht admin subdirectory
i dont know how to do this

Answer (score 0):

TEMPLATE_DIRS should contain a list of directories to the templates. So if you want to replace the admin template with your own, one way to do it is to create a folder in your project directory, say let's call it "G:\Semester 6\SE\code 1\mysite\templates\", put your justified template in "G:\Semester 6\SE\code 1\mysite\templates\admin\base.html" (assuming you want to modify the base.html template), then you put your TEMPLATE_DIRS like so:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [
    "G:\\Semester   6\\SE\\code 1\\mysite\\templates\\",
]
```

note that the back slashes need to be doubled because back slash denotes the escape character in Python string and settings.py is a python module so it had to conform to Python syntax. Another alternative solution is to replace the back slash with forward slash, Windows understand both path separators.